# Using Geoserver WFS POST and format_options=PRJFILEFORMAT?

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, shapefile, wfs

I'm using geoserver (2.4.4) to provide users with shapefile downloads. Some of the software the shapefiles are going to be used in requires .prj-files that follows the "ESRI-standard". A bit of searching lead me to a Geoserver ticket ([GEOS-4503](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-4503)), and by downloading esri.properties from there and placing it in my %GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR%/user_projections folder I can issue a GET request to:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/bw/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ns:layername&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP&format_options=PRJFILEFORMAT:ESRI
```

and i get back a zipfile with (amongst the other files) a .prj-file with the following:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]
```

This is fine, as my data is in EPSG:4326 and the string above is indeed the "ESRI-type" I want.

However, i also need the user to filter their data, so I've figured that I need to use a filter, and thus POST an XML-file like this:

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0"  
                xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
                xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
                xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
                http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
                <wfs:Query typeName="ns:layername" srsName="EPSG:4326">            

            <ogc:Filter> 
                <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <PropertyName>version</PropertyName>
                    <Literal>56</Literal>
                </PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Filter>

                </wfs:Query>
            </wfs:GetFeature>
```

to an url like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/bw/ows?outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP&format_options=PRJFILEFORMAT:ESRI
```

I also get a zip-file with the data back, but this time the .prj file has this content:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84", DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], AUTHORITY["E
PSG","6326"]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST]
, AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

And this is indeed the OGC-prj-format.

(In addition to setting format_options=PRJFILEFORMAT:ESRI I've also tried to check the "Use ESRI WKT format for SHAPE-ZIP generated .prj files" box in the WFS-page in the geoserver GUI).

Why does the override of prj-file-format work on a GET but not on a POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging (thanks to Andrea for clarifiction) I ended up trying a couple of things more or less on random.

I've found that in order to get ESRI-style-prj-files from a WFS POST request you have to be sure of two things:

1. Check the box "Use ESRI WKT format for SHAPE-ZIP generated .prj files" box in the WFS-page in the geoserver GUI"
2. Send your POST-request to the /geoserver/ows or /geoserver/wfs endpoint (and NOT to the /geoserver/NS/wfs endpoint.

So, you *have* to set the GUI option to use ESRI format and you *cannot* use an URL that includes the namespace. In addition, the format_options=PRJFILEFORMAT:ESRI query-param does not have any effect.

Comment: Regarding the namespace issue: as long as you go to the WFS-settings page for your namespace and check "Use ESRI WKT format for SHAPE-ZIP generated .prj files" box in the WFS-page in the geoserver GUI" there it's fine to use the namespace in the url

Answer (score 2):

It may be related to the different version of the WFS protocol you used in the two requests. Not sure, I  was not the one to implement GEOS-4503

Comment: Nice catch. I'm rather certain that I've tried version=1.1.0 in the non-working case as well, but i'll re-test

Comment: The WFS-POST returns the same result when specifying version=1.1.0.